# VBA code works only in the debugging mode and hangs when running in normal mode

Tags: excel, vba

This problem is driving me crazy. I have the following code:

```
'unprotect sheet
If.Range("Start").Row+1<.Range("End").Row then
  .Rows(.Range("Start").Row+1 & ":" & .Range("End").Row-1).Select
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  'protect sheet
End if
```

when I run it in debugging mode and trace the code, it works perfectly. But when run the code in a normal mode (not debugging) it gives me an error message as " select method of Range class failed" This errors happens in the line: `.Rows(.Range("Start").Row +1 ....`
that is just after the IF statement. 
Any ideas? 
Please help.

Comment: Please use the Code Sample button ("1010 101") to reformat your question.  It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error usually means you are trying to select a range that belongs to a non-active sheet.

You *almost* always [don't need to select anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683):

```
.Rows(.Range("Start").Row+1 & ":" & .Range("End").Row-1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked. So, what I did, whenever I select a range anywhere in the code, I activate the corresponding sheet first then I select. 
Thanks a lot! It was very helptul!