# How can I select a cell, given its row and column number?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a cell by giving which row and column to use.

It is giving me an error:

> "Unable to get the select property of the range class."

when I get to this line:

```
Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol).Select.Paste
```

Here is a short snippet of my really long code:

```vb
Dim etfCol As Integer, etfCount As Integer, currRow As Integer, currRowValue As String
etfCol = 1   'Just select the first column
etfCount = Sheets("Automated Table").Cells(Rows.Count, etfCol).End(xlUp).Row
'Repeat for every row.
For currRow = 5 To etfCount
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Copy and paste the ticker
    Cells(currRow, etfCol).Copy
    Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol).Select.Paste
Next
```

Am I getting this error because "etfCount" is the value I got from "Automated Table" sheet, and I am trying to use that for "Ticker" sheet?
This is the only reason I could think of, but that doesn't wholly explain this error.

I tried debugging the code.

Comment: You need to [select the sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902841/11683) before you can select a range on that sheet. When you fix that, you will have error 424 "Object required" because `.Select` does not return a `Range`, so `Select.Paste` makes no sense. Once you fix that by moving `Select` and `Paste` onto different lines, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683 for why you never needed `Select` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol).Select.Paste
```

with:

```
Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol).Paste
```

This assumes that `Sheets("Automated Table")` is active.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.Select` ([which is not a good practice in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)), you may profit a lot by the Macro Recorder. Just record the copy and the paste and examine the code:

```
Sub Makro4()
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

As you see, the `.Select` and the `.Paste` are on various lines and so they should stay. In your code it should be:

`Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol).Paste`
`Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol).Paste`

Or you may do it a bit better:

```
With Sheets("Ticker").Cells(currRow, etfCol)
     .Select
     .Paste
End With
```

Anyway, as pointed out in the link, the usage of `Select` is not to be encouraged. (Although it works).