# Runtime error 1004. Select method of range class failed. in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form that adds information to a sheet.  The data is added to the sheet by clicking an "ADD" button.  Once added to the sheet, It then selects all data in the sheet to sort and format.

The Workbook is defined as WB set to ThisWorkbook
The Worksheet is defined as WS and set to WB.Worksheets("Transactions")

The data is added without any issue, However when trying to select all data to format, i now get the "runtime" error.

In the code below, i = 28

```
With WS
    .Range("A2:F" & i).Select <<<---- on this line
    .Range("F" & i).Activate
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1:C" & i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal  ' sorts by date
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1:B" & i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal  ' sorts by type
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D1:D" & i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal ' sorts by income or outgoing

' Further sorting and formatting continues below ......

End with
```

First I removed the variables from the range selection and used

```
With WS
    .Range("A2:F28").Select 
    ..........

End with
```

However this results in the same error.

I also tried setting WB to ActiveWorksheet instead of ThisWorksheet, in case it was trying to select cells from a different open workbook. However it has just written the data to the correct worksheet

I then tried to remove the use of .select

```
With WS
   With .Range("A2:F" & i)
    '.Range("F" & i).Activate
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1:C" & i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal  ' sorts by date
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1:B" & i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal  ' sorts by type
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D1:D" & i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal ' sorst by income or outgoing
    End With
End With
```

But this creates an error "Unable to get the Sort property of the Range class"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902841/8422953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The error you mention is because you cannot use `Select` on a range of a non-active sheet. However, you don't need to.

(2) The Sort error is a little tricky. You nest 2 `With`-statements. In that case VBA will first look to the "inner" `With`-statement, in your case the Range. Now a Range has a `Sort`-method and the VBA runtime thinks you want to access that. However, that sort is a (one-line) method that you can call, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.range.sort
However, the code that you have is valid for a `Sort`-Object. This `Sort`-object exists for a Worksheet, not a Range, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.range.sort

So either you remove the inner `With`-clause to that the `Sort`-object of the sheet is used or you call the specific `Sort`-method for a Range.