# IF statement in VBA code failing for each next

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete filtered rows from an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets. I used a dynamic range because each sheet doesn't have the same number of rows.

I have tried to use the `If` statement to make the code loop through some specific sheets but it won't work. The code doesn't move to other sheets without `ws.Activate`.

```vb
Sub DeletAnalyst2()
    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, startcell As Range, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long

    'Set Objects    
     Condition = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please type the condition text:")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate

        If (ws.Name <> "Presentation") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet6") And (ws.Name <> "sheet11") And (ws.Name <> "PrefTracks") And (ws.Name <> "AnalystNeeds") And (ws.Name <> "Post-Preference") And (ws.Name <> "Post Preference Grid") Then
            Set startcell = Range("A1")
            'Find last row and column of cells
            lastrow = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            lastcol = Cells(startcell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            'select dynamic range
            Range(startcell, Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Select

            'AutoFilter technique
            'ws.Range(startcell, ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
            Range(startcell, Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Condition
            'deleting filtered
            Selection.Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I expect code to loop through some sheets but not all sheets.

Comment: `doesn't move to other sheets without ws.Activate.` - because you need to [qualify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17733541/11683) each `Range` and `Cells` call with `ws`.

Comment: Ex: use `Set startcell = ws.Range("A1")` instead of `Set startcell = Range("A1")`. [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) may also be useful.

Comment: When I do Set startcell = ws.range(A1) the codes throws errors at Range(startcell, Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Select

Hey Gserg, did you mean defining all the ranges for each worksheet?

Comment: The if statement doesn't work for this code. Code is lopping through all sheets and that is not what I want.

Comment: @Meera do you have same issue for my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221976/11167163) ?

Comment: @Meera You are supposed to add `ws` to every single `Range` and `Cells` call. Not just the outer `ws.Range(Cells, Cells)`, but `ws.Range(ws.Cells, ws.Cells)`.

Comment: @GSerg this is my first vba code.

Comment: @GSerg I added ws to the range but run into an error - lastrow = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @Meera Where's the `ws` in front of the outer `Cells`?

Comment: @GSerg this is where it fails   ws.Range(startcell, ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Select. The error says select method of range class failed.

Comment: @Meera That most likely means that [`ws` is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592881/11683).

Comment: @GSerg I activated the ws and run into an error at - Selection.Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlUp. This is because the macro is working on a sheet that should not be included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [qualify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17733541/11683) all calls to `Range` and `Cells` with the worksheet they belong to, otherwise you will be inadvertently referring to cells from the active sheet.

You [do not need](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) to `Select` anything either.

```vb
Sub DeletAnalyst2()
    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, startcell As Range, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim Condition As String

    'Set Objects
    Condition = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please type the condition text:")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      Select Case ws.Name
      Case "Presentation", "Sheet6", "sheet11", "PrefTracks", "AnalystNeeds", "Post-Preference", "Post Preference Grid"
        'Do nothing
      Case Else

        With ws
          Set startcell = .Range("A1")

          'Find last row and column of cells
          lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
          lastcol = .Cells(startcell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

          'select dynamic range
          With .Range(startcell, .Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Condition
            .Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlUp
          End With

          .ShowAllData
        End With

      End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @GSergThe code runs the first time but fails to loop through and throws an error at - Selection.Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: the problem is without ws.activate the code does not loop through the various sheets. After I enter ws.activate, the code tends to loop through all sheets even though we have specified that those sheets be excluded.@GSerg

Comment: @Meera You should not add `ws.activate` to this code. It works without it.

Comment: code is working just threw a runtime error '1004. No cells were found for some of the conditions. How do I avoid that error?

Comment: @Meera That depends on where it happens and what you want to do when it happens.